# Nonexistence of three functions with $F_1(a)+F_2(b)+F_3(c) = abc$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How can I show that there aren't any three functions $F_1, F_2, F_3$ from $\mathbb R^+ \rightarrow \mathbb R^+$ so that:

$$F_1(a)+F_2(b)+F_3(c) = abc$$

for any $a,b,c \in \mathbb R$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose for the sake of contradiction that there exists such functions. Fix $b = c = 0$, then $F_1(a) = -F_2(0) - F_3(0) = \mbox{constant}, \forall a \in \mathbb{R}$. The same for $F_2$ and $F_3$. Thus we have $abc = F_1(a) + F_2(b) + F_3(c) = \mbox{a constant}, \,\, \forall a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}$ which is absurd.

Answer (score 1):

Taking the triple $\{a,1,1\}$ we get $$F_1(a)=a-F_2(1)-F_3(1)$$

Similarly we have: $$F_2(a)=a-F_1(1)-F_3(1)\;\;\&\;\;F_3(a)=a-F_1(1)-F_2(1)$$

Add these three equations together.  We get $$a^3=F_1(a)+F_2(a)+F_3(a)=3a-2(F_1(1)+F_2(1)+F_3(1))=3a-2$$

But this clearly does not hold for all $a$.

Answer (score 0):

By taking $b=c=1$ we have
$$F_1(a)=a-F_2(1)-F_3(1)\ .$$
Doing similar things for $b,c$ and substituting back we have
$$a+b+c-2(F_1(1)+F_2(1)+F_3(1))=abc\ ,$$
that is,
$$a+b+c-2=abc\ .$$
But this equation clearly does not hold for all $a,b,c$.

Answer (score 0):

If you set $a=b=0$, you find
$$ 0=F_1(0) + F_2(0)+F_3(c), $$
so $F_3$ is constant. But this is impossible, since the only dependence on $c$ on the left-hand side of the original equation is in $F_3$, whereas its right-hand side is linear in $c$.